# How to change order of plots in pandas hist command

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a set of histograms for a dataframe  with 25 columns named `"Feature_1","Feature_2",...."Feature_25"`. When I use `df.hist()` it sorts individual histograms by their names so they are plotted in the following order: `"Feature_1",""Feature_10","Feature_11"..."Feature_2","Feature_20",...`
which is not what I need.

How do I change the sorting order? Passing columns parameter doesn't change anything.

I solved the problem by using matplotlib directly but that's not what I would prefer to do each time I need to plot several histograms.

Comment: Although annoying, could you rename the columns `Feature_01`, `Feature_02`, ....?

Comment: While that would solve the problem in this particular case  it wouldn't solve the problem in general when we have several columns with unordered names.

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem is hardcoded into `pandas.DataFrame.hist` since [`df.hist` points to `pandas.tools.plotting.hist_frame`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L5473).  [This line](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tools/plotting.py#L2833) shows that if your columns are sortable, it will sort them using vanilla `sorted(columns)`.  There does not appear to be a keyword to change this behavior.

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks. I see. Wonder what are the benefits of such behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You could instead make repeated calls to hist with individual columns. Not sure if that fits all of your needs.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1,3],
                  'b':[1,1,2,1,3],
                  'c':[2,2,2,1,3],
                  })

df[['c']].hist()
df[['a']].hist()
df[['b']].hist()
```

Just iterate through the list of the columns in the order you would like

```
my_list = ['c','a','b']
for each in my_list:
    df[[each]].hist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making the columns index categorical, then plotting with sort_columns True.

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[30,10]})
df.columns = pd.CategoricalIndex(['b', 'a'], ordered=True)
df.plot.hist(sort_columns=True, subplots=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the columns ahead of time using df.reindex_axis with a custom sorting key. Then the columns can be in the order that you want. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature_1':[1,2,3],'Feature_10':[1,2,3],'Feature_2':[2,3,4]})
print df
df = df.reindex_axis(sorted(df.columns, key=lambda a: int(a.split('_')[1])), axis=1)
print df
```

Gives you

```
Feature_1  Feature_10  Feature_2
0          1           1          2
1          2           2          3
2          3           3          4
   Feature_1  Feature_2  Feature_10
0          1          2           1
1          2          3           2
2          3          4           3
```

Then plot the histogram

```
df.plot.hist(sort_columns=False, subplots=True)
```